# Postgres: How to improve CASE WHEN performance on update case?

Tags: postgresql

Please See function below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_cluster_key(
    table_name text,
    which_cluster_key text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE query text; catnum text; catnum_c text; name text; namep text;
BEGIN

IF which_cluster_key = 'ven' THEN

    which_cluster_key = 'cluster_key_ven';
    catnum = '"New Discerned VCN"';
    catnum_c = '"New Discerned VCN2"';
    name = '"New Vendor"';
    namep = '"New Vendor Parent"';
    ELSE IF which_cluster_key = 'mfr' THEN
    which_cluster_key = 'cluster_key';
    catnum = '"New Discerned MCN"';
    catnum_c = '"New Discerned MCN2"';
    name = '"New Mfr"'; 
    namep = '"New Mfr Parent"';

    ELSE RAISE EXCEPTION  'ERROR: %', 'In create_cluster_key function. Please Choose ven or mfr!';
    END IF;
END IF; 

    query := '
    ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS "Key_MCN";
    ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS "Key_VEN";
    ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS '||which_cluster_key||';


    ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' ADD "Key_MCN" varchar;
    ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' ADD "Key_VEN" varchar;
    ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' ADD '||which_cluster_key||' varchar default '''';

    DROP INDEX IF EXISTS idx_'||replace(table_name,'"','')||' ;
    CREATE INDEX idx_'||replace(table_name,'"','')||'
    ON '||table_name||' 
    USING btree
    ("Client DBID","New Mfr Parent","New Vendor Parent","New Discerned MCN2" COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

    --============================== FROM TABLE=====================
    --=========================
    --ST JUDE & '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%AVGJ%''
        update '||table_name||' set '||which_cluster_key||' = (
        CASE
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''DS0600%'' THEN ''DS0600_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''ESP100%'' THEN ''ESP100_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%9TVLP%'' THEN ''9-TVLP_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%AFASE%'' THEN ''AFASE_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%9EITV%'' THEN ''9-EITV_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%9EXCH%'' THEN ''9-EXCH_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''DAVSE%'' THEN ''DAVSE_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''DS2N0%'' THEN ''DS2N0_CLS'' 
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%LDA2%'' or '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%LDP2%'' THEN ''LDA2_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%AEHP%'' THEN ''AEHP_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%ACP2%'' THEN ''ACP2_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%AGFN%'' THEN ''AGFN_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%AFHP%'' THEN ''AFHP_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%AECJ%'' THEN ''AECJ_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%AHPJ%'' THEN ''AHPJ_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%CSGW%'' THEN ''CSGW_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%TFGT%'' THEN ''TFGT_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%MECJ%'' THEN ''MECJ_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%MHPJ%'' THEN ''MHPJ_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%UCLP%'' THEN ''UCLP_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%9DEL%'' THEN ''9-DEL_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%9ITV%'' THEN ''9-ITV_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%9TV2%'' THEN ''9-TV2_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%9TV4%'' THEN ''9-TV4_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''9PLUG%'' THEN ''9-PLUG_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%9VSD%'' THEN ''9-VSD_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%E100%'' THEN ''E100_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%AVGJ%'' THEN ''AVGJ_CLS''                                   
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%AVP%'' THEN ''AVP_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%ASD%'' THEN ''ASD_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%PDA%'' THEN ''PDA_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''B10%'' THEN ''B10_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''BSP%'' THEN ''BSP_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''CD1%'' or '||catnum_c||' ilike ''CD2%'' or '||catnum_c||' ilike ''CD3%'' THEN ''CD1-2-3_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''PRT%'' THEN ''PRT_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''9GW%'' THEN ''9-GW_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''9SB%'' THEN ''9-SB_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''9SD%'' THEN ''9-SD_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''9PF%'' THEN ''9-PF_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',3) in (''S60'',''S65'',''S70'',''S75'') THEN ''S-XX_CLS''      
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',4) ilike ''%AJ'' or left('||catnum_c||',4) ilike ''%MJ'' THEN ''AJ-MJ_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''C120%'' THEN ''C120_CLS''       
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%AGN%'' THEN ''AGN_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''LPA%'' THEN ''LPA_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''TF%'' THEN ''TF_CLS''
        ELSE ('||which_cluster_key||') END  
        )
        WHERE '||which_cluster_key||' = '''' and '||name||' ilike ''%ST JUDE%''
        ;       
    --=========================


    --"ANDOVER HEALTHCARE INC"

        update '||table_name||' set '||which_cluster_key||' = (
        CASE 
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''3100%'' THEN ''3100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20flyer.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''3150%'' THEN ''3100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20flyer.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''3200%'' THEN ''3100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20flyer.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''3300%'' THEN ''3100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20flyer.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''3400%'' THEN ''3100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20flyer.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''3600%'' THEN ''3100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20flyer.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''5100%'' THEN ''5100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlexNL%20lr.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''5150%'' THEN ''5100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlexNL%20lr.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''5200%'' THEN ''5100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlexNL%20lr.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''5300%'' THEN ''5100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlexNL%20lr.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''5400%'' THEN ''5100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlexNL%20lr.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''5600%'' THEN ''5100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlexNL%20lr.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''7100%'' THEN ''7100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/healthcare/cohesive.html?id=45#top
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''7150%'' THEN ''7100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/healthcare/cohesive.html?id=45#top
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''7200%'' THEN ''7100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/healthcare/cohesive.html?id=45#top
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''7300%'' THEN ''7100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/healthcare/cohesive.html?id=45#top
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''7400%'' THEN ''7100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/healthcare/cohesive.html?id=45#top
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''7600%'' THEN ''7100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/healthcare/cohesive.html?id=45#top     
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''9100%'' THEN ''9100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20LF2.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''9150%'' THEN ''9100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20LF2.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''9200%'' THEN ''9100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20LF2.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''9300%'' THEN ''9100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20LF2.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''9400%'' THEN ''9100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20LF2.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''9600%'' THEN ''9100_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20LF2.pdf       
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''7800%'' THEN ''7800_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20LF2.pdf
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''8840%'' THEN ''8840_CLS'' --http://www.andoverhealthcare.com/pdf/CoFlex%20LF2.pdf
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',4) in (''3710'',''3715'',''3720'',''3725'',''4725'',''4730'',''3730'',''3740'',''3760'') THEN ''3760_CLS'' --http://andoverhealthcare.com/sports/cohesive_bandages.html?id=62#top
        ELSE ('||which_cluster_key||') END  
        )
        WHERE '||which_cluster_key||' = '''' and '||namep||' = ''ANDOVER HEALTHCARE INC''
        ;

    --"BLOCKADE MEDICAL LLC"

        update '||table_name||' set '||which_cluster_key||' = (
        CASE 
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%FR10'' THEN ''FR10_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%FR18'' THEN ''FR18_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%CF10'' THEN ''CF10_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%FN10'' THEN ''FN10_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''%FL10'' THEN ''FL10_CLS''
        ELSE ('||which_cluster_key||') END  
        )
        WHERE '||which_cluster_key||' = '''' and '||namep||' = ''BLOCKADE MEDICAL LLC''
        ;

        --===================

    --"EXACTECH INC"

        update '||table_name||' set '||which_cluster_key||' = (
        CASE 
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201235%'' THEN ''0201235_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201236%'' THEN ''0201236_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201242%'' THEN ''0201242_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201244%'' THEN ''0201244_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201245%'' THEN ''0201245_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201247%'' THEN ''0201247_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201248%'' THEN ''0201248_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201249%'' THEN ''0201249_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201250%'' THEN ''0201250_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201251%'' THEN ''0201251_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201260%'' THEN ''0201260_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201261%'' THEN ''0201261_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''0201265%'' THEN ''0201265_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''050002%'' THEN ''050002_CLS''               
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''01010%'' and  right('||catnum_c||',3) in (''195'',''245'') THEN ''01010_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''13022'',''13028'',''13032'',''13036'',''13040'') THEN ''13040_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''13222'',''13228'',''13232'',''13236'',''13240'') THEN ''13240_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''13622'',''13628'',''13632'',''13636'',''13640'') THEN ''13640_CLS''               
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''13822'',''13828'',''13832'',''13836'',''13840'') THEN ''13840_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''13422'',''13428'',''13432'',''13436'',''13440'') THEN ''13440_CLS''           
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''16000'',''16010'') THEN ''16010_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''16001'',''16011'') THEN ''16011_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''16050'',''16051'') THEN ''16051_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''16070'',''16071'') THEN ''16071_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''16020'',''16030'') THEN ''16030_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''16021'',''16031'') THEN ''16031_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''16022'',''16032'') THEN ''16032_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''16023'',''16033'') THEN ''16033_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''34038'',''34065'') THEN ''34065_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''34040'') THEN ''34040_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''32036'',''32038'',''32040'',''32046'') THEN ''32046_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''31021'',''31022'') THEN ''31022_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''20430'',''20432'',''20434'',''20436'',''20438'',''20440'',''20446'',''20448'') THEN ''20448_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''20805'',''20806'',''20807'',''20808'') THEN ''20808_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''20461'',''20462'',''20463'',''20464'',''20465'',''20441'',''20442'',''20443'',''20444'',''20445'') THEN ''20465_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''20056'',''20057'',''20062'',''20072'',''20063'',''20073'',''20064'',''20074'',''20065'',''20075'') THEN ''20075_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''20002'',''20003'') THEN ''20003_CLS''
        WHEN left('||catnum_c||',5) in (''12065'',''12265'') THEN ''12265_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''02010%'' THEN ''02010_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''05002%'' THEN ''05002_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''10260%'' THEN ''10260_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''EXACT%'' THEN ''EXACT_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''10220%'' or '||catnum_c||' ilike ''BP28%'' THEN ''10220_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''14240%'' THEN ''142-22-00_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''15802%'' THEN ''15802_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''18000%'' or '||catnum_c||' ilike ''18001%'' THEN ''18001_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''18800%'' or '||catnum_c||' ilike ''18801%'' THEN ''18801_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''SPC%'' THEN ''SPC_CLS''
        ELSE ('||which_cluster_key||') END  
        )
        WHERE '||which_cluster_key||' = '''' and '||namep||' = ''EXACTECH INC''
        ;

        --===================

    --"ATRION CORPORATION"

        update '||table_name||' set '||which_cluster_key||' = (
        CASE 
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''RCL%'' or '||catnum_c||' ilike ''RCC%'' or '||catnum_c||' ilike ''RCB%'' THEN ''RCB_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''RCK%'' THEN ''RCK_CLS''
        ELSE ('||which_cluster_key||') END  
        )
        WHERE '||which_cluster_key||' = '''' and '||namep||' = ''ATRION CORPORATION''
        ;
        --===================

    --SIENTRA INC

        update '||table_name||' set '||which_cluster_key||' = left('||catnum_c||',5)||''_CLS''
        WHERE '||which_cluster_key||' = '''' and '||namep||' = ''SIENTRA INC'' and length('||catnum_c||') > 7
        ;
        --===================

    --SIENTRA INC

        update '||table_name||' set '||which_cluster_key||' = (
        CASE 
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''ALLOX%'' THEN ''ALLOX_CLS''
        ELSE ('||which_cluster_key||') END  
        )
        WHERE '||which_cluster_key||' = '''' and ('||namep||' = ''SIENTRA INC'' or '||namep||' = ''SPECIALTYCARE INC'')
        ;

        --===================
    --"APPLIED MEDICAL TECHNOLOGY INC"

        update '||table_name||' set '||which_cluster_key||' = (
        CASE 
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''M11%'' THEN ''M11_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''M12%'' THEN ''M12_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''M15%'' THEN ''M15_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''GJ1%'' THEN ''GJ1_CLS''
        WHEN '||catnum_c||' ilike ''RS%'' or '||catnum_c||' ilike ''RL%'' THEN ''RL_CLS''
        ELSE ('||which_cluster_key||') END  
        )
        WHERE '||which_cluster_key||' = '''' and '||namep||' = ''APPLIED MEDICAL TECHNOLOGY INC'';
        ';
    EXECUTE query;

--==============================
    RETURN 'Done!';
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION create_cluster_key(text, text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

This function just show small of update query. Full function have > 200 update query.

I ran this function on table which have millions of rows, It take 8 minutes to get the result. I would like to improve the performance further. Any suggestion What it can be done?

My server: 72GB Râm, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU l5520 @ 2.27GHz

Comment: What have you done already? There are heaps of information on postgresql performance, both on the official site and on independent resources.

Comment: I'm not a developer, I try to learn about sql and excel for my work. I also read some postgresql tutorial and some posted in this site, and i think i don't have enough knowledge to understand it clearly. So, i posted here to find the help